# How to close a file, Opened using os.system("audio.mp3") after is has completed playing in python?

Tags: python

I have a script which opens the audio file opened using os.system("audio.mp3") in python. I need that file to close and return to the python shell my program is running.
+"&*")

```
def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    os.system("audio.mp3")
```

Comment: The audio length me vary according to input. So I cant use the sleep method.

Comment: What are you doing with the file? Playing it?

Comment: Have you checked subprocess module? I think it is what you need.

Comment: See my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working? The only error I got when executing your code had to do with `os.system("audio.mp3")`, and read:

> sh: audio.mp3: command not found

But this has nothing to do with your file not closing, so I am not sure this was your problem? Anyways, I countered it by installing mpg123 which is a program to play MP3 files via the command line.

I then tried the following code in Python3.4 running inside my terminal and it worked fine:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from gtts import gTTS
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> def speak(audioString):
...     print(audioString)
...     tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
...     tts.save("audio.mp3")
...     os.system("mpg123 audio.mp3")
... 
>>> speak('test')
test
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.23.8; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes


Terminal control enabled, press 'h' for listing of keys and functions.

Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: audio.mp3 ...

MPEG 2.0 L III cbr32 24000 mono

[0:00] Decoding of audio.mp3 finished.
>>>
```

Furthermore, `ps aux | grep -i audio` tells me that `audio.mp3` isn't running in the background anymore.